How would you approach patching these drywall holes?
My drywall experience is patching smaller holes, and I recently re-taped and repaired my bathroom. But this is at a friend's house I wanted to help out.  I'm not sure what I should do especially about this skinny outlet one. Should I try to screw a backer board to the stud and then to the drywall on the other side?  And then fill, tape, and finish? Or should I cut a larger section out to get to both studs?

This one maybe I'll just cut a square. I had a hard time with the new drywall not being level with the old when I did my bathroom. Maybe I need some shims or something this time.

This one seems like a smaller version of the first one, but maybe annoying since the hole for the box looks too big so you still see it when the faceplate is installed.


I am not a fan of California patches.
For areas where you have no support:
Cut small pieces of thin plywood or baseboard trim that are 1" wider than the opening. Put a screw in the center of piece and use it as a handle to navigate it into the hole. Anchor the  wood into the surrounding drywall. Cut a piece of drywall to fit the hole.
For areas where you do have support:
Cut a piece of drywall to fit the hole.
Anchor the drywall to the support.
Mud, tape and sand.
I like to cut both the surrounding drywall and the patch half the width of the drywall tape, remove the surface paper, apply mud to the joint and then tape. You don't get as much of bump from the joint and there is much less need to feather the joint to blend into the existing wall.

My drywalled use what he called "hot patches" which could be what @DelphicOracle refers to as "California patches".
He would cut a piece of drywall maybe 2 inches larger on both dimensions than the hole to be patched and the score one side the size of the hole. He would then break off the dry wall leaving the paper on the one side of the drywall that is larger than the hole. Then he would insert the drywall into the hole with the extra paper on the surface and some mud under it. Then add more mud on the surface and let it dry to the next day.
He said he had done patches like this up to 12" by 12" for people's houses where partygoers had busted holes in the wall and their parents were to be returning in the next few days. Talk is  cheap but patching a receptacle size hole should not be a problem.
Good Luck!
